# Expressing an xpath xml elements' union as a child of a common parent in XSLT/XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am trying to do something like the pseudocode xpath `//noah/(shem or cham or yefet)` inside an xslt stylesheet and while I can do `//noah/shem | //noah/cham | //noah/yefet` I also have the case of a 2*2 crossproduct case  which gets ugly fast.

The actual stylesheet is [here](https://github.com/shlomif/fortune-xml/blob/master/XML-Grammar-Fortune/module/extradata/fortune-xml-to-html.xslt) and I am trying to add a `fact` alias to `f` and a `lang` alias to `l` for [this XML input](https://github.com/shlomif/shlomi-fish-homepage/blob/master/lib/factoids/shlomif-factoids-lists.xml)  that consists of factoids about people and things ( Chuck Norris/etc. ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 2 and later you can actually use `//noah/(shem, cham, yefet)` or `//noah/(shem | cham | yefet)`. With XPath 1 you are restricted to `//noah/*[self::shem or self::cham or self::yefet]`.